# Best way to read and parse bytes read from InputStream

Tags: java, android, inputstream

What would be the most efficient way to read 13 bytes from `InputStream`one byte at a time until end of the frame char 0xEE is read and also parse the data to `Integer` and `float`. The actual data is 4 bytes long so there is three 4 bytes long data and then end of the frame char.

```
private final InputStream mmInStream;
public void run() {

    BufferedInputStream bInputStream = null;
    DataInputStream dInputStream = null;
    byte[] buffer;
    byte readByte = 0;
    int i = 0, bytesAvailable = 0;
    bInputStream = new BufferedInputStream(mmInStream);
    dInputStream = new DataInputStream(bInputStream);

    // Keep listening to the InputStream while connected
    while (true) {

        try {
            bytesAvailable = dInputStream.available();

            if(bytesAvailable > 0) {

                buffer = new byte[bytesAvailable];
                Log.d(getClass().getName(), String.format("value = %d", bytesAvailable));
                do {
                    readByte = dInputStream.readByte();
                    buffer[i] = readByte;
                    i++;
                } while(readByte == 0xEE);

                threadHandler.obtainMessage(BluetoothClientActivity.MESSAGE_READ, bytesAvailable, -1, buffer).sendToTarget();

            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: There is exactly *one way* of reading single bytes. That makes it the most efficient way as well, by simple logic chosing from a set of options of size one always yields that one option. Whats the point of asking?

Comment: I am new to Java so just asked to be sure.

Comment: Ok, but when starting learning *efficiency* should be your *least* concern, really. Worry about *correctness* of the results first, you can worry about anything else *later*. Only worry about efficiency when its proven a problem: "Premature optimization is the root of all evil" - thats especially true when you start worrying before you've even written any code.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap a `DataInputStream` around a `BufferedInputStream` around your `InputStream` and use the various `DataInput` `readXXX()` methods as necessary.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I edited the main post with the code snippet. Is that what you meant?